# How to craft witcher's gear before lvl ~20?

Tags: the-witcher-3

So to craft a lvl 7 griffin silver sword I need to find an master blacksmith, for which there is high leveled quest. 
The screenshot is in polish but at the bottom right you can see 'Kowal' (blacksmith) - Mistrz (master).
When I played the game on hard difficulty I didn't have this problems.

Is there a way to craft it before being myself high leveled?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try going to a journeyman smith for the Griffin armor and swords. It appears that this is just displayed wrong in the Polish version. I just changed the language to see it for myself and in the Polish version it does say master smith but in the English one it says that you need to go to a journeyman smith, so this just seems to be an error in the Polish text.

I had the Griffin armour crafted by a journeyman armourer at Crow's Perch in Velen and the weapons by a journeyman weaponsmith in Oxenfurt, but there are also such smiths in Novigrad.

[image]

Comment: Yeah this appears to be it. I successfully crafted the weapons in Oxenfurt. Thanks :)

Comment: While English has progression of `begginer->journeyman->master` Polish version does `journeyman->master->grandmaster` (in direct translation). So it's not badly displayed, it's just translated weirdly.